# Intitialiazation of auto veriable and function calls

Tags: int

Actually in one of the written test i was being asked these questions and i was not able to answer then after i tried on my vc++ compiler so can any body help in these questions

```
1)
int main()// case ::1
{
   int variable=10,20;// here in assigning 20 compiler was giving error
}
```

but

```
int main() // case ::2
{
   int variable ;
    variable=10,20;
    printf("%d \n",variable);// without any error it prints value 10

}
```

2)

```
int main()
{
   function(12,(13,(14,15)));


}

void function(int varible1,int variable2 )
{

  printf("%d %d \n",variable1, variable2);// prints 12 and 15

}
```

how come ???
so can any one tel me the internal process behind these...
Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

The result of an expression containing a comma is the value of the last sub-expression. All sub-expressions get executed though.

```
int x;
cout << (x = 30, "Hello!"); // Outputs "Hello!"
cout << x; // Outputs 30
```

In the expression

```
variable=10,20;
```

both

```
variable=10;
```

and

```
20;
```

get executed (the first assigns 10 to variable and evaluates to 10, the latter does nothing but evaluates to 20)

In

```
int main()
{
    function(12,(13,(14,15)));
}
```

The function gets called with arguments 12 and (13, (14, 15)) which evaluates to 12 and (14, 15) which, in turn, evaluates to 12 and 15.

The first example you give is the incorrect use of the shortcut to define two integers:

```
int x = 10, y; // Defines two integers, x and y
```

Since, in your example, 20 is not a valid name for a variable the compiler complains.